# Ubuntu ssh clients

Tags: command-line, nautilus, ssh, client, filezilla

is there a ssh client similar than filezilla but i all so need to use terminal sometimes. Support for ssh access key is all so requirement. It would be great if i just could jump up and down files in graphical view and when needed just popup window and use terminal commands in my server.

Can i for example use Nautilus and terminal? Or does ssh access key mix things up? I mean when access key is saved, does both programs how to use access key?

Edit: I try to make my question more clear. :) I'm building my very first server setup but i haven't been able to get server on line, just checking how things should work.

Comment: Can't you just use SSH in terminal?

Comment: Yes, i could do that. But it would be much easier life for me.. :)

Answer (score 3):

ssh in a terminal, scp to transfer files, and sshfs to mount a remote file system.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

and post back if you have a specific problem

Comment: I recommend using sftp rather than scp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this leads me to right direction..

Answer (score 1):

You can use winscp. Its another power full scp tool to connect scp on linux .

Also some ultimate tools list :

```
Gftp
Kasablanca
Fireftp
Kftpgrabber
Winscp on wine
GNOME Commander
Site copy
File runner
Konqueror
```